# Converting all values in nested object

Tags: javascript

Having array like this:

```
fs= [ { "Val1" : "A", "Val2": 2.123, "Val3": 2.122 }, 
{ "Val1" : "B", "Val2": 3.123, "Val3": 2.112 }, 
{ "Val1" : "C", "Val2": 2.2134, "Val3": 2.122 }]
```

How is it possible to change all the float to int numbers- so omitting values that are strings?

My current attempt is:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fs)) {
  Object.keys(value).forEach(key => { Math.round(value[key])})
}
```

However this way it will change strings to NaN values, but I want to keep them the same and change floats only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `typeof` check first, and make sure to use the result of the rounding:

```js
const fs = [ { foo: "don't change me", "Val1" : "A", "Val2": 2.123, "Val3": 2.122 }, 
{ "Val1" : "B", "Val2": 3.123, "Val3": 2.112 }, 
{ "Val1" : "C", "Val2": 2.2134, "Val3": 2.122 }]

const newFs = fs.map(obj => (
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([key, val]) => [key, typeof val === 'number' ? Math.round(val) : val]
    )
  )
));
console.log(newFs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the value is a number by using `!isNaN(value)` which will return true for a numeric value even if it is in a string

```js
fs = [{
    Val1: "A",
    Val2: 2.123,
    Val3: 2.122
  },
  {
    Val1: "B",
    Val2: 3.123,
    Val3: 2.112
  },
  {
    Val1: "C",
    Val2: 2.2134,
    Val3: 2.122
  },
];

result = fs.map((f) =>
  Object.keys(f)
  .map((k) => ({
    [k]: !isNaN(f[k]) ? parseFloat(f[k]) : f[k]
  }))
  .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a,
    ...b
  }), {})
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, something like this?:

```
fs.forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => {+v !== +v ? void(0) : o[k] = ~~v;}))
```

beware it mutates fs, slicing wont help. Replace ~~ with round if you dont want float truncation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use .reduce 
This code will work doesn't matter how many keys, key names, their types you have in each object.

```js
let fs = [ { "Val1" : "A", "Val2": 2.123, "Val3": 2.122, "Val4" : "wfA" }, 
{ "Val1" : "B", "Val2": 3.123, "Val3": 2.112, "Val4" : "3.42" }, 
{ "Val1" : "C", "Val2": 2.2134, "Val3": 2.122 }]

let one = fs.map(it => Object.keys(it).reduce((acc,rec) => {
  typeof it[rec] !== 'number' ? acc[rec] = it[rec] : acc[rec] = ~~it[rec]
  return acc}, {}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(one))
```